# Sack method in Ajax does not work in chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The following code snippet do not work in chrome,

I declared this variable in my .JS and the method is successfully executed in IE.
But do not work in chrome, it's not even invoking the method sack()

```
var object = sack();
```

Also tried with

```
var object = new sack();
```

Please suggest what is the alternative to call this ajax method so that it works both in IE and chrome devices.

Comment: What is `sack();` can you post the function definition?

Comment: Kindly refer the link - @scunliffe http://learninghub.une.edu.au/javascript/SACK/docs.html

Comment: please add the HTML source code that you are using on your page. If you can't post all of it, please post all of the `<script>` tags and their contents

Comment: PS I just noticed on that SACK documentation that the last time it was updated was 2006.  I'm not sure what this library really does, but it looks like it could easily be replaced with something much easier like jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: created a test html page referencing the .js and invoked the new sack() with no errors, and returned an object - tried it in the console of the developer tool too. tested it with Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97